# How to cache MySQL table in C++ web service

Tags: c++, mysql

I've got a big users table that I'm caching in a C++ web service (BitTorrent tracker). The entire table is refetched every 5 minutes. This has some drawbacks, like data being up to 5 minutes old and refetching lots of data that hasn't changed.
Is there a simple way to fetch just the changes since last time?
Ideally I'd not have to change the queries that update the data.

Comment: Prefetching allows me to respond to requests without any MySQL queries, which is great (required) for performance.

Comment: How many web servers are we talking about?  Facebook uses memcached for this.

Comment: Just one process on one server

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate possibilities come to me:

1. MySQL Query Cache
2. Memcached (or similar) Caching Layer

I would try the query cache first as it likely is far easier to setup. Do some basic tests/benchmarks and see if it fits your needs. Memcached will likely be very similar to your existing cache but, as you mention, you'll to find a better way of invalidating stale cache entries (something that the query cache does for you).

Comment: The MySQL Query Cache is bad for performance and it'd still require me to query MySQL for every request, which I don't have time for. The service can currently do 5000+ requests/s (single-threaded), which leaves me less than 0.2 ms per request. Memcache would have the same problems as my current cache, wouldn't it?

Comment: You'd have to test it before you could say whether it is too slow or not simply due to the large number of variables involved. Depending on the complexity/size of your query I wouldn't really be surprised with sub millisecond execution times. If the query cache does prove to be too slow then an faster caching layer (like Memcached or your own cache) is the next step. This requires you to manage the cache items manually, ideally by replacing cache entries with their new value whenever you update them.

Comment: I should say that whether the query cache is useful or not depends on a lot of factors which is why I say "test it" first.